# AngularJS one-way binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind an input (one-way), whoever if I change its value its no longer binding properly

```
    //controller => on row click => change input
    $scope.getNote = function (note)
    {
        $scope.currentNote = note;
    };

   //view
   <input type="text"  value="{{currentNote.Title}}" >
```

This is the scenario, getNote is being called and the input is being filled properly. However, when I change the value of the input and call getNote again the input doesn't show the new value even tho its value attribute contains the correct value. So somehow its not showing the correct value to the end user.

eg: 
1- First Value from GetNote = "Hello World" 
2- I change the value of the input to "Foo" as a normal user
3- Call GetNote again and the I get value="Hello World" but on the screen it displays "Foo"

**Hack Solution:**

```
//controller object value copy using jquery
$scope.currentNote = jQuery.extend({}, note);

//view
<input type="text"  ng-model="currentNote.Title" >
```

**Am hoping for an Elegant solution**

Comment: You need to use  `<input type="text"  ng-model="currentNote.Title" >`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with ngValue directive, as sbaaaang said. But without curly braces (documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

Edit:

And maybe if you just want to use one-way data binding a div will be enough for your purposes, and not an input. Then you can style it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

use **ng-value=""** instead of **value=""** should fix

i would do:

```
$scope.getNote = function (note)
    {
        $scope.currentNote = note;
    };

   //view
   <input type="text" ng-model="currentNote.Title" ng-value="currentNote.Title" />
```

If you still getting problems try also:

```
$scope.getNote = function (note)
        {
            $scope.$on(function () {
             $scope.currentNote = note;
            });
        };
```

Comment: just tried that but now nothing is showing for the end user, even tho i can see the value change inside firebug

Comment: so try using **ng-model=""** usually forms need it ;) @rtp i updated the answer

Comment: ng-model is working properly but i want a one-way binding not two way :(

Comment: @rtp yeah remove {{ }} from the ng-value="" expression and it will work, updated answer

Comment: same problem, after i change the value its not rebinding properly

Comment: @rtp post more of your code if you can, that part is now correct the problem is somewhere else i guess

Comment: @rtp also try **$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.currentNote = note; });** instead